# Remove undefined from type

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0, typescript-generics

I use `typeof` to infer the return type of a function, but since I cannot call the actual function I use a trick using the ternary operator to infer the type, however this leaves me with a union type that includes `undefined`:

```
function foo() {
  return { bar: 1 };
}

const fooInstance = true ? undefined : foo(); // foo() is never actually called
type FooOrUndefined = typeof fooInstance;     // {bar: number} | undefined 
type Foo = ???;                               // Should be { bar: number }
```

Is there any way to get rid of `undefined` from `FooOrUndefined`?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You will want to use [`NonNullable`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype):

```
type Foo = NonNullable<FooOrUndefined> // { bar: number; }
```

[Sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=7&ssc=59&pln=7&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMOcAUBKRBvAUIxAJwFMoRCltEAjAQ0IC5EBGRAXwG5c3dcIEAzlGSoAkmCG1IxRAF5EUQiBkB%20ROAAmxYDDDENiJinQYOiAPTmRJxDAGI9AN2KFEtaCFoAbLwE9EEN5e%20rhQvgAOMgBiqADyhACqYFo6egbyYZFwwNbiktJmBASWOHSMDiAAttQubIgAPurJ2rr6iKER0ahyiAByCL0gPrTUwQA8MXDxSSmtGgB8FlZUZUxgVTWEZmxAA)

Comment: Is there a way to do this to a nested type/interface?

Comment: @Daniel for nested types/interfaces you want `Required` (https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype)

Answer (score 12):

If you just want to remove `undefined` but keep `null`, you can do a small util:

```js
type NoUndefined<T> = T extends undefined ? never : T;

type Foo = number | string | null | undefined;

type Foo2 = NoUndefined<Foo> // number | string | null
```

Answer (score 3):

[ford04 pointed me to `NonNullable`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59771339/167251), but I also discovered that [`ReturnType`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet) is a cleaner way of achieving what I'm trying to do:

```
function foo() {
  return { bar: 1 };
}
type Foo = ReturnType<typeof foo>; // { bar: number; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Exclude` type of **Utility Types** of TypeScript:

```js
function foo() {
  return { bar: 1 };
}

const fooInstance = true ? undefined : foo(); // foo() is never actually called
type FooOrUndefined = typeof fooInstance;     // {bar: number} | undefined 
type Foo = Exclude<FooOrUndefined, undefined>;// { bar: number }
```